# How to keep original values of an entity while reloading related entities using Entity Framework Core when ModelState is not valid?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

Using ASP.NET Core and Entity Framework Core.

When editing a record, I also load related "child" entities used for display purposes in the edit form.

If the user submits a form with missing required fields, then `ModelState.IsValid` is false. *So far so good.*

When returning the non-updated values to the user (with an error message), how can I keep the original values posted by the user and also reload related entities?

In the following simplified example the `dbcontext` queries the client record and includes the associated state table to display the state name.

If the `ModelState` is not valid, the client record is returned to the user with the values the user submitted - but all the related `.Include` entities are null at this point. How can I repopulate the `.Include` entities without overwriting the view model submitted?

```
// GET
public async Task<IActionResult> Edit(int clientId)
{
    var client = _context.Client
                         .Include(x => x.State)
                         .Where(w => w.client_id == clientId
                         .FirstOrDefault();
    return View(client);
}

// POST
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public async Task<IActionResult> Edit(clientModel)
{
   //verify: last_name
   if (clientModel.last_name == null)
   {
       ModelState.AddModelError(string.Empty, "Last name is required");
   }

   if (ModelState.IsValid)
   {
      // Update the record and redirect
      await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
      return RedirectToAction(nameof(Index), new { client_id = clientModel.client_id });
   }

   // model state is not valid! Return record submitted to the edit view
   // *** MISSING THE VALUES FROM THE RELATED ENTITY clientModel.State at this point
   return View(clientModel);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

First the `State` navigation property should be `virtual` then you can load it using `await _context.Entry(clientModel).Reference(x => x.State).LoadAsync();`

if the related is a collection then you can use `await _context.Entry(clientModel).Collection(x => x.Collection).LoadAsync();`

another way is to get data from context and assign it

```
var client = _context.Client
                         .Include(x => x.State)
                         .Where(w => w.client_id == clientId
                         .FirstOrDefault(); 


 //or just get the state .. var state = _context.State..
clientModel.State = client.State;
return View(clientModel);
```